# WCF net.TCP traffic clarification

Tags: multithreading, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have implement a WCF service that implement call back.
I have client web app connect to WCF via HTTP API
and Remote client app, that run in windows OS and connect to WCF using net.TCP include callback support.

now client send actions to remote and remote execute them and return status by callback return value.

I have a thread, that every 2min send ImAlive (call bool WCF.ImALIVE(machineID)) to keep the net.TCP alive if there is no activities.

My question:
if I get callback action from client, and while remote execute it ImAlive thread wakeup and call WCF.ImALIVE, is there will be any issue of block or deadlock or time out?

Comment: Keeping dedicated threads available for specific callers is probably not a good idea. Can you store the server side client session state data in a way that can be loaded up or checked by any thread (thread safe data access)? If you can do this then you won't keep threads tied up which can service other client requests while clients are idle.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ServiceBehavior ConcurrencyMode, read more here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and.

Here is also a duplicate of what you are trying.
[Use WCF Service with basic authentication user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456259/use-wcf-service-with-basic-authentication-user)

You can see this related question also, but related to instancing on server side.
[Сan I use PerCall instancing and Reentrant concurrency in the same service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697005/an-i-use-percall-instancing-and-reentrant-concurrency-in-the-same-service)